# Puppeteer wait for popup page to load completely before procedding

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to wait for a popup to load completely before proceeding but i am not sure how to accomplish this, currently i am using a `await page.waitFor(3000);`. Is there a more elegant way to do this and wait for the popup to fully load and then proceed.

below is my relevant part of the code.

```
        await page.evaluate(async () => {
          await $('#myDataExport').click();
          await $('.export-btn a').click();
        },);
        await page.waitFor(3000);
        const browserPages = await browser.pages();
        const exportPopup = browserPages[browserPages.length - 1];
```

I have also tried to use the below

```
await Promise.all([
 await page.click('.export-btn a'),
 await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' }),
]);
```

But I get an error `Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement`

Any help in this would be really great, Thanks.

Comment: have you tried ? ```await page.waitFor(<elementName>)``` or ```{waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}```

Comment: @MayankGupta yes, i have updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a working example. You can just ignore the request interception code.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

;(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
    const [page] = await browser.pages()

    // This network interception due to massive ads on the page
    // You can remove this if you like, as this is just an example
    // page.setRequestInterception(true)
    // page.on('request', request => {
    //    if (request.url().startsWith('https://www.w3schools.com/')) {
    //        request.continue()
    //    } else {
    //        request.abort()
    //    }
    // })

    await page.goto('https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'})
    const [popup] = await Promise.all([
        new Promise(resolve => page.on('popup', resolve)),
   
        // THE LINES COMMENTED BELOW IS JUST AN W3SCHOOL EXAMPLE
        // page.waitForSelector('a[target="_blank"].w3-btn.w3-margin-bottom'),
        // page.click('a[target="_blank"].w3-btn.w3-margin-bottom'),
    
        // YOUR CODE SHOULD LIKE THIS
        page.waitForSelector('.export-btn a'),
        page.click('.export-btn a'),
    ])

    await popup.waitForSelector('#iframeResult')
    await popup.screenshot({path: 'targetpopup.png'})
    await popup.close()

    await browser.close()

})()
```

Comment: if i use waitForSelector, i get this error `Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement`

Comment: The waitForSelector also just an example for W3Schools website.
You should find any selector that match within your desired webpage URL.

Comment: I've edit my answer, please check to make it works smoothly on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: [`browser.once`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.0&show=api-eventemitteronceevent-handler) with [`targetcreated`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/#event-targetCreated) target domain event?

> Calling `target.page()` connects Puppeteer to the tab and generates a `Page` object.
>
> New tabs aren't opened immediately on click. A way to await events is to create a new promise. [[source]](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/386#issuecomment-343059315)

**Example:**

```js
const newPagePromise = new Promise(resolve => browser.once('targetcreated', target => resolve(target.page()));
await page.click('.export-btn a');
const newPage = await newPagePromise;
```

Comment: hi @theDavidBarton, thanks for your reply. In my case the popup in not a new tab but a new popup window, will this still work in that case?

Comment: I suspect it could work, yes. I've seen such e2e test examples over GitHub using this method, however I haven't got the chance to try it, as I don't have such popup usecase. If you can give me an example site I can check it... but by that time you could also try it :)

Comment: i did try it but it looks like the process just hangs and does not proceed further

Comment: I see. If `await page.waitFor(3000);` does the trick I think it is an acceptable way, especially as the api doesn't provide direct solution to await popups.

Comment: ok, thanks. Also, a related question i had was, if i am opening popups in a loop, do i need to create `newPagePromise ` inside the loop or need to create it outside just once?

Comment: I'd definitely go for: **outside** the loop. Also If it isn't decided yet and you'd take my advice: I suggest to use regular `for` or a `for...of` loop instead of a forEach (as promises work differently inside forEach and Array.map than we'd expect).